# How to find all the network interfaces in windows ce?

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-ce

In my C# application I need to identify all the network interfaces of my device running on windows ce 6.0.

In dot net full framework I am able to use

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

but I don't see the same namespace and class in compact framework.
I need the code similar to `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to run the windows command "netsh" and parse the output:

Command:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Outputs:

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet 1
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Wi-Fi
```

Comment: When I try to execute the command on cmd.exe I am getting "Cannot execute netsh.exe"

Comment: @shivkumar try `wmic nic get NetConnectionID`. It shows regular connection interfaces including those that have been disabled.